# Need to configure SMTP settings on IIS for the ASP.Net Core Identity server for the EMail verification

Tags: smtp, iis-6, asp.net-core-3.1, configurationsection

I successfully deployed the Identity server and it is working fine also configure the SMTP settings on the VPS but when try to set up it with the ASP.Net Core 3.1 Application unable to find the SMTP in the features using IIS.
I used No Managed Code As Application Pool.
Below is the image regarding my problem
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .net core no need for asp.net setting. It was needed in the older version. We just need to change the configuration in appsettings.json for (SMTP) email setup also for the MTA(Third Party)

Answer (score 1):

I used sendgrid for MTA inshort configure SMTP with sendgrid. Issue is to add its secret andAPI key in the appsettings.production.json 
Below is the Code:

```
   {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"       
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "SendGridUser": "Put User name Here",
  "SendGridKey": "Put API Key Here",
  "RequireConfirmedEmail": true
}
```

It didnt't required to setup SMTP for the site only need to configure the SMTP for the main IIS Node it works for it.